# Could I have poisoned myself by using my gas fireplace with the flue closed?

Tags: fireplace, gas

Ive been using my vented gas fireplace for a couple weeks not knowing the flue was closed. How dangerous is this.  I have myself & 3 dogs that were in my family room with me where the fireplace was burning.  I'm worried I've poisoned my poor babies.

Answer (score 3):

If they are not dead, and you are not dead, none of you got poisoned enough to matter. Just don't do that again.

Buy a carbon monoxide detector (or two, or three), and put a note on the fireplace reminding you to open the flue.

Answer (score 1):

Well you and the dogs aren't dead, so that's a good sign.

I wouldn't keep doing it, though. Venting carbon monoxide into your living space isn't great for your health.

Comment: ...you owe me a frothy hopped beverage ;-)

Comment: Haha, we posted like a second apart!

Answer (score 0):

Some gas fireplaces have been sold that are designed to be used without venting, on the argument that they aren't producing more CO/CO2 than a gas oven would. I've never been convinced that I believe the argument, and would definitely recommend installing a combined CO/gas alarm as a basic safety precaution; compared to the cost of the gas fireplace, they're a cheap investment.

(I do like a good fire, but not enough that I was interested in the hassles and heat loss of a real fireplace. My current plan is to set up a large flatscreen in a mock fireplace surround and call that good enough. Maybe add an IR heater if I can figure out how to disguise it, to reinforce the illusion.)